# UIAlertView with 3 textfields and 3 labels overlap each other

Tags: ios, xcode, uialertview

I'm trying to create an UIAlertView with 3 TextFields and 3 Labels.

But with my current code they just go over each other, I've tried to change the frame of the AlertView and I've tried to use the CGAffineTransform but they both didn't work.

Here's my code:

```
UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sign in" message:@"\n\n\n\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Stop" otherButtonTitles:@"Sign in",nil];

UILabel *customerIdLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 55, 65, 21)];

customerIdLabel.tag =1;
customerIdLabel.text = @"Customer id: ";
[myAlertView customerIdLabel];

UITextField *customerIdField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(89, 50, 160, 30)];

customerIdField.tag = 2;
customerIdField.placeholder = @"Fill in your customer id";
[myAlertView customerIdField];
```

And then there's two more combinations of those.

Here's the transform that I've tried:

```
CGAffineTransform myTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 0.5f);
[myAlertView setTransform:myTransform];
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you aren't supposed to use UIAlertViews like that. You're supposed to set the title, message, etc and use the [alertview show]. The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html) seems to be pretty clear that it is an as-is class.The UIAlertViewStyle may be something you can look at, but the options are 1 text field, 1 secure field, or a username and password field.

Your best option is to use a new UIViewController and use the [presentViewController:animated:completion:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController%3aanimated%3acompletion%3a) call.

Answer (score 0):

I get around this by not changing UIAlertView but add a clear view on top of it when it is showing (you can pad with spaces) and add the textfields there at the correct location (note when rotation occurs). Then, let the tap go through the view to the UIAlertView. This has gone through Apple in 3 apps in the store.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how you did it? I'm pretty new to this

Answer (score 0):

Before the new SDK in xcode 5 you where able to add subviews to an alert view but that doesn't work anymore. I had to update an app because of that nasty code. Is better to use uipopovercontroller for ipad or show a UIView or even present a viewcontroller for either ipad or iphone.